# Play sound when opening folder (AppleScript)

Tags: applescript

Pretty new to this.

I'm trying to figure out how to play an audio file when opening a folder without any windows opening or using any external apps. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean opening a folder in _Finder_? If so, please update your question to say so.

Answer (score 0):

The general technique you are looking for is called *"Folder Actions"* - these are scriptable actions that can be triggered when you open/close a folder or create/delete a file.

Select the following piece of Applescript and copy it with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>.

```
on opening folder this_folder
    do shell script "afplay '/System/Library/Sounds/Hero.aiff'"
end opening folder
```

- Now start the `Script Editor` by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>␣</kbd> (that's `Cmd` and `SPACEBAR`) and starting to type `Script Editor`. As soon as it guesses what you mean, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Paste the script above into the editor using <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, and go to `File`->`Save` and then navigate to `$HOME/Library/Scripts/Folder Actions Scripts` and save the script as **Script Bundle**, calling it `SoundOnOpen`. You will probably have to create the `Folder Actions Scripts` folder if you have never done this before. If you cannot see your `Library` folder in Finder, click <kbd>⇧</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> and type `$HOME/Library` in the box and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Now, create a folder on your Desktop, calling it `Musical` and right-click on it. Mouse over `Services` and left-click `Folder Actions Setup...` then assign the script we created above to this folder.

Open the folder in Finder and it will bong!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make life a little easier for yourself, I would suggest creating a new script editor file, allowing you to choose the audio file you would like to use on your folder action.  In this new AppleScript document, just enter this code:

```
choose file
```

and then click the “Run” button.  This will open a file chooser window, allowing you to go to any directory on your computer and choose any audio file you would like to use.

[image]

After you choose your file, copy the entire text from the result window.  Now it's time to create your new folder action.  Create a another new script editor document and place your cursor at the top of the document and Ctrl+Click

[image]

[image]

---

Now remember you copied that file information from the result window in the “choose file” script.  Paste that information into your code as you can see in my sample Image.

[image]

```
on opening folder this_folder
    set a to alias "Macintosh HD:Users:Smokestack:Music:iTunes:iTunes Media:Music:Pink Floyd:Dark Side Of The Moon - 30th Anniversary SACD:09 Brain Damage.mp3"
    set p to POSIX path of a
    do shell script "afplay -t 25 " & quoted form of p
    (* The "-t 25" Is just an option telling afplay shell script to only play the audio for 25 seconds.  You can adjust that number to what ever you would like or remove that part of the command completely.
    the code below this line is what you would use if you don't want a time limit on the audio
    do shell script "afplay " & quoted form of p  *)
end opening folder
```

Now compile and save your script to your /Users/YOUR_SHORT_USER_NAME/Library/Workflows/Applications/Folder Actions

The next thing you want to do is open your Folder Actions Setup.app which you can find here: /System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Folder Actions Setup.app

Because you saved that AppleScript folder action file to that specific location, it will now be available in your Folder Actions Setup.app when you choose “attach script to folder”

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure why you say my script will have a problem with music files that contain spaces - the filename is correctly enclosed in single quotes and works fine even if I play a file with a space in its name.

Comment: My bad… I just noticed after you mentioned about your single quotes. I will revise my answer